# rails has_secure_password. is it possible to change user's password in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I have rails project with user's authorization with has_secure_password. So, password store in DB as encrypted password.

Now I want to add following: 
User will be able to change his current password to new password and this new password must be encrypted in DB too.

I can not find any information about it.

Is there way to do it with has_secure_password?

Comment: If you are using `password`(attribute) field while authenticating, then you can provide the same `password` attribute for update in the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this in console:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.password = 'test123'
user.password_confirmation = 'test123'
user.save
```

So this will update the user with new password. If you want to use it `update_attributes` then:

```
user.update_attributes(password: 'test123', password_confirmation: 'test123')
```

This will update the user's password which will be in encrypted form. You don't need to do anything for that rails will handle it on update.

Or if you are using `strong parameters` and that has:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

And you have this in params:

```
 Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"test123", "password_confirmation"=>"test123"}}
```

then you can just use this in your update action:

```
user.update(user_params)
```

Hope this helps.